# LWJGL: Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW$Functions

Tags: lwjgl

Trying out LWJGL and trying to make the demo run: https://www.lwjgl.org/guide. The Java code is simply copy-pasted from the site.

I'm using Ivy within Eclipse to fetch the libraries:

```
<ivy-module version="1.0" xmlns:extra="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
  <info organisation="foo" module="bar"/>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.lwjgl" name="lwjgl" rev="3.1.0"/>

    <dependency org="org.lwjgl" name="lwjgl-glfw" rev="3.1.0"/>

    <dependency org="org.lwjgl" name="lwjgl-opengl" rev="3.1.0"/>

    <dependency org="org.lwjgl" name="lwjgl-opengles" rev="3.1.0"/>

    <dependency org="org.lwjgl" name="lwjgl-bgfx" rev="3.1.0"/>

    <dependency org="org.lwjgl" name="lwjgl-platform" rev="3.0.0">
      <artifact name="lwjgl-platform" type="jar" extra:classifier="natives-linux"/>
      <artifact name="lwjgl-platform" type="jar" extra:classifier="natives-osx"/>
      <artifact name="lwjgl-platform" type="jar" extra:classifier="natives-windows"/>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

On running the HelloWorld application I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW$Functions
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwTerminate(GLFW.java:717)
    at HelloWorld.run(HelloWorld.java:54)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:132)
```

My Eclipse setup:

[image]

Not sure what I am missing here.

Thanks for any help.